# Issue with inserting null value array property using Dapper and Npgsql2

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I'm currently investigating a problem with executing an insert using Dapper's Execute in conjunction with the Npgsql2 managed provider for PostgreSQL 9.3.

**Table Structure (simplified):**

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  title TEXT NULL,
  tags TEXT[] NULL,
  created timestamp NOT NULL,
);
```

**Related Entity (simplified):**

```
[Table("posts")]
internal class Post
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string[] Tags { get; set; }
  public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

**Offending Code**

```
using (var ts = CreateTransactionScope())
{
    using (var con = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection())
    {
        var post = new Post();
        post.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;
        post.Title = "Foo bar baz";
        con.Insert(post);

        ts.Complete();
    }
}
```

The code above utilizes Dapper.Contrib's SqlMapperExtensions which calls Dapper.Execute with the following SQL and param:

**SQL:**

```
insert into posts (title, tags, created) values (@Title, @Tags, @Created)
```

**Param:**

```
Id  0  int
Created  {14.07.2010 19:15:51}  System.DateTime
Title  "Foo bar baz"  string
Tags  null  string[]
```

What happening when the command is executed is that the driver complains about parameter **@Tags** being referenced in the insert statement but not present in the command's **Parameters** collection. Dapper simply fails to emit it. This only seems to happen for array type properties. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably simply a bug; there is special handling on postgres for arrays, which changes the way dapper works in a few places; it looks like one of those places (`PackListParameters`) only considered the non-null scenario. I've moved some code around; if you are open to [pulling the code from github](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) and trying it locally, I'd be very grateful. Hopefully it now works (note: NuGet not yet updated).

Comment: I just ran a rather big batch import against the latest dapper commit and the problem appears to be gone. No other issues either.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold k, thanks; that'll be in the next NuGet drop